# Display javascript variables in html

Tags: javascript, css, json, variables, show

I have this list in html:

```
<div style="padding-left:30px;">
        <ul style="list-style-type:circle; margin-top:0px;">
                <li><a href="http://printoriente.com/tarjetas-presentacion/">Tarjetas de presentacion</a><label>I want the JS variable HERE</label></li>
                <li><a href="http://printoriente.com/afiches/">Afiches</a><label>I want the JS variable HERE</label></li>
                <li><a href="http://printoriente.com/volantes/">Volantes</a><label>I want the JS variable HERE</label></li>
                <li><a href="http://printoriente.com/fotos/">Fotos</a><label>I want the JS variable HERE</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need the (data.refPrice) variables where I indicated "I want the JS variable HERE":

```
<script>

$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/tarjetas-presentacion", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
});

$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/afiches", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
});

$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/volantes", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
});

$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/Fotos", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
});

</script>
```

Comment: avoid hardcoding css styles if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create labels or spans with unique id's as placeholders.  Then set the content of the span

```
$('#yourid1').html(data.refPrice)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this off the top of my head:

```
<li id="afiches"><a href="http://printoriente.com/afiches/">Afiches</a><label>I want the JS variable HERE</label></li>
```

Then in your js:

```
$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/afiches", function( data ) {
  console.log(data.refPrice);
  $('#afiches').html(data.refPrice);
});
```

Comment: Its works buy I did it and generates conflicts with the rest of site. I need another solution.

Comment: Care to explain what conflicts it generates?

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to your `<a>`, then use `html()` or `text()`

```
<li><a id="myId" href="http://printoriente.com/tarjetas-presentacion/">Tarjetas de presentacion</a><label>I want the JS variable HERE</label></li>

$.getJSON( "http://api.printoriente.com/price/tarjetas-presentacion", function( data ) {
  $("#myId").html(data.refPrice);
});
```

Comment: Its works buy I did it and generates conflicts with the rest of site. I need another solution.

Comment: If you have conflicts, you have problems with ID. You should really understand why...